# Pyspark: how to extract statistics from a table?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+-----+
|                  ID|               time|count|
+--------------------+-------------------+-----+
|378101ee32a648ef0...|2020-01-01 11:00:00| 2900|
|ff5d5840742d42beb...|2020-01-01 23:00:00| 1615|
|ff5d5840742d42beb...|2020-01-01 22:00:00| 1589|
|a06f198b200364fb0...|2020-01-01 01:00:00| 1571|
|18991cb9b06c4dbde...|2020-01-01 01:00:00| 1514|
|aaf20cfe4ebc98ca8...|2020-01-01 19:00:00| 1462|
|35e96b1170613db44...|2020-01-01 17:00:00| 1324|
|0eb82275984a3eef0...|2020-01-01 16:00:00| 1305|
|0eb82275984a3eef0...|2020-01-01 17:00:00| 1305|
```

I would like to write a query that returns a table with some statistics for each hour related to `count` of each IDs

For instance I would like a table like the following:

```
       time              mean     median     min    max    5thPercentile  95thPercentile
2020-01-01 00:00:00       33        27.5      2    2000       3.4            1300        
2020-01-01 10:00:00       33        27.5      2    2000       2.6            1120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation.  I think this does what you want:

```
select time,
       avg(count),
       (max(case when tile = 10 then count end) +
        min(case when tile = 11 then count end)
       ) / 11,
       max(case when tile = 1 then count end) as percentile_05,
       max(case when tile = 19 then count end) as percentile_95
from (select t.*,
             ntile(20) over (partition by count) as tile
      from t
     ) t
group by time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pyspark.sql` to create panda's DataFrame-like object.

Then you can call [describe()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe) to see statistics about your data.

Example from docs:

```
>>> df.describe(['age']).show()
+-------+------------------+
|summary|               age|
+-------+------------------+
|  count|                 2|
|   mean|               3.5|
| stddev|2.1213203435596424|
|    min|                 2|
|    max|                 5|
+-------+------------------+
```